# Servlet mapping issue - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, mapping

It's my first Java EE "app". I am a little bit confused... After googling I think I'm doing everything correct, but if it was so, I wouldn't come across problems : )

My form under save.jsp:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/save">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="idTxtName" >Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="idTxtName" name="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="idTxtSurname" >Surname:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="idTxtSurname" name="surname"/></td>
            </tr>
                    ... etc...
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save person" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I've tried also:

```
form method="post" action="/save"
```

as well as

```
form method="post" action="save"
```

My Servlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import // etc

    public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                       // some actions
        }
    }
```

And web.xml mapping:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SavingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.SaveServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SavingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/save</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

After submitting my save.jsp form I see a classic message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SImpleCRUD/save
type Status report
message /SImpleCRUD/save
description The requested resource is not available.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my mapping incorrect?

Comment: Check whether the application is deployed properly.

Comment: What is `SImpleCRUD`? Is it the name of your web application?

Comment: Which URL do you use to arrive to your jsp?

Comment: @AlexR Yes, it is my project's name ; I go to save.jsp starting from index.jsp (definied in web.xml: <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>) via link <a href="save.jsp">Go to saving page</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times it's happen.There is nothing wrong in your code. But just restart your server and run again. May be it will work fine.

In JSP **action="SavingServlet"** and
**@WebServlet("/SavingServlet")**  Configure this annotation in class level of your Servlet. Now no need to configure your servlet in **web.xml**

Comment: Adding an annotation helped indeed. But why it doesn't work with standard non-annotation approach? Do you have any idea? I've restarted tomcat a few times with no result (before adding annotation?) : )

Comment: @guitar_freak It should be work like that also. May bu you did not configure exact servlet in your configuration file. may be that's the problem.

Comment: @guitar_freak If this answer is helped you make it correct to future uses for others.

Comment: @guitar_freak Your form's action should have only `save`, not the context

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this is a proper way to solve this error. But Its works for me.

Change your `web.xml` to like this and try

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SavingServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/save.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SavingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/save</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Its Working fine in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your form's action should have only `save`:

```
<form method="post" action="save">
```

Without the context ('`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/`')